# Java support for non english regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to validate the user names (contains only alphabet). But the user is entering in Spanish. I cannot use the common regx [A-Za-z].
Is it possible to validate this using java regular expressions?.
Any suggestion on a different approach is also fine?

Comment: Read [this](http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/68749.aspx) !

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161507/regex-for-spanish-alphabets-in-coldfusion-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unicode based letter symbol:

```
\\p{L}
```

Also you can create your pattern with [`Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) option to get unicode support:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

Comment: You may also need to specify `UNICODE_CASE` as a flag on `Pattern.compile()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\p{IsAlphabetic}`, or in the case of Spanish you could use `[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÑñÜü]` Spanish is my first language :-)